# Why isn't my Sinon spy function working when called in a promise then clause?

Tags: node.js, promise, sinon

I'm writing a test for a Promise-based function. To be specific, it's a React component & I'm testing to ensure the onChange handler is called correctly.

My component looks like this:

```
class TextInput extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            value: props.value || '',
        };

        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }

    updateState(values) {
        return new Promise(
            (resolve) => {
                this.setState(values, () => { resolve(this.state); });
            }
        );
    }

    onChange(event) {
        this.updateState({ value: event.target.value })
            // then fire the onChange handler (if necessary)
            //
            .then((state) => {
                if (this.props.onChange) {
                    // console.log(this.props.onChange) shows that this IS a
                    // Sinon spy function
                    this.props.onChange(state.value);
                }
            })

            .catch((err) => { console.log('-----------', err); });
    }

    render() {
        // render the component (omitted to keep this short)
    }
}
```

My test looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import chai from 'chai';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import TextInput from '../../../../client/modules/components/TextInput';

const expect = chai.expect;

describe('TextInput component editing', () => {

    it('calls the onChange handler', () => {

        const onchange = sinon.spy();

        const value = '';
        const editedValue = 'something';

        const component = mount(<TextInput value={value} onChange={onchange} />);

        // change the value
        //
        component.find('input').simulate('change', {
            target: { value: editedValue }
        });

        expect(component.find('input').prop('value')).to.equal(editedValue);

        expect(onchange.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
        expect(onchange.calledWith(editedValue)).to.equal(true);
    });
});
```

The test fails on the last two `expect` calls.

If I replace the sinon spy with a plain old function, the function is called. E.g.,

```
// instead of this...
// const onchange = sinon.spy();

// do this...
const onchange = (value) => { console.log(`VALUE = ${value}`); };
```

If I use the callback for the `setState` method directly, it works. E.g.,

```
// instead of...
// this.updateState(values).then(...)

// do this...
this.setState(values, () => {
    // call the onChange handler...
});
```

I could do this, but I want to avoid it because I'm going to add more functions to this component and I don't want to get trapped in the [pyramid of doom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_of_doom_(programming)).

At first I thought it might have something to do with a problem with `this` in the scope of the `updateState` method or one of the callback functions within that method, but adding `console.log` statements throughout show that `this` is referring to an instance of `TextInput` in all the appropriate places.

Adding a `console.log` statement to dump the `onChange` handler just before it is fired shows that `this.props.onChange` is, in fact, a Sinon spy.

I've looked at other packages, such as [sinon-as-promised](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinon-as-promised), but I don't think that package really addresses what I'm trying to do - I just want to ensure my callback is called within the promise `then` clause. `sinon-as-promised` is a package to stub out an entire promise.

I'm probably overlooking something straightforward, but whatever it is, I'm not seeing it.

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary that `this.props.onChange` gets called when the state has changed (and not when the state is _going_ to be changed)? The issue is that your state change methods are async, but your test isn't (and I don't think that there's a very clean solution).

Comment: Thanks @robertklep, you've got me thinking more about the problem. For this purpose, async is not necessary, but I wanted to use the callback on `setState` to a) ensure that the change was actually made before continuing (which I admit may or may not actually make a difference) and b) to implement the promise for semantic reasons (chaining steps in a multi-step process and avoiding the pyramid of doom).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your synchronous tests are finishing before your async calls to state are executed. I won't comment on whether you should be both setting state and calling on change methods and when. But I think your current simple answer is to just use an async test by passing in the `done` argument. (obviously you don't really even need a spy at that point, but I left it in just to show it's not the spy that's not working per se:

```
describe('TextInput component editing', () => {
  it('calls the onChange handler', done => {
    const fakeOnChange = stuff => {
      expect(spyOnChange.calledOnce).to.equal(true);
      expect(editedValue).to.equal(stuff);
      expect(component.find('input').prop('value')).to.equal(editedValue);
      done();
    }

    const spyOnChange = sinon.spy(fakeOnChange);

    const value = '';
    const editedValue = 'something';

    const component = mount(<TextInput value={value} onChange={spyOnChange} />);

    component.find('input').simulate('change', {
        target: { value: editedValue }
    });

  });
});
```

Comment: I was going to suggest something similar. My only issue with it (but one that can't be fixed easily) is that when `fakeOnChange` never gets called (due to a bug in the component), the test will time out (which of course is an indication that something is wrong, but it would still be better to be able to test explicitly if an event handler got called or not). That's why I asked (in my comment) if being async is absolutely necessary to begin with.

Comment: I'm currently going with the callback function on `setState` and it's working fine. This is a case where I want to get the code working, rather than worrying too much about the most elegant solution. But thanks for your answer - if I ever get a chance to refactor this code & make it pretty, I'll be doing something like this.